# React-Navigation animated Tab nav inside a Stack nav

Tags: javascript, iphone, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

I am using [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) to create a Stack navigation. One of the cards inside stack navigation is a screen containing a tab navigation.

The tab and stack navigation works fine when initially loaded, but after navigating to another card inside the stack navigator and then back to the card containing the tab navigator the app crashes. It doesn't give any clear error messages, but simply quits the simulated app.

Setting `swipeEnabled: false` and `animationEnabled: false` in tab navigator seems to prevent crashing. Problem is we need these features for the tab navigation.

My guess is that the Tab navigators and Stack navigators animations and/or gestures are clashing. Another fix would be disabling animations and gestures for the stack navigation, but I haven't found a way to do that.

```
const AppTabNavigator = TabNavigator(
    {
        Tab1: { screen: Tab1 },
        Tab2: { screen: Tab2 },
        Tab3: { screen: Tab3 },
    },
    {
        swipeEnabled: false,
        animationEnabled: false,
    },
);
```

[image: Component hierarchy]

How to have hierarchy like in the picture and still have animations and gestures enabled for the tab navigation?